# Error occur from creating asset twice on Hyper Ledger fabric example

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I got this error from trying to use `CreateAsset()` function twice.[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1S2S.png)

Does anyone know the cause of this? or what can I do to fix it?

I was playing with the fabric-samples and wanted to try to create asset as many as possible with `CreateAsset()` function. But I encountered a problem when you added the second `CreatAsset()` to the process.

I was using go chaincode from tutortial repo. Nothing is changed, only added 1 line of `CreateAsset()`.

Comment: Please share your error message in the format of `plain text`

Comment: error message is given in image format

Answer (score 0):

The asset-transfer-basic sample also has an example of how to unpack the additional information associated with a transaction invocation error. That would likely give you an error message (from the endorsing peer) that explained the reason for the failure.

If you look at the smart contract implementation, the first thing CreateAsset does is:

```
exists, err := s.AssetExists(ctx, id)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if exists {
    return fmt.Errorf("the asset %s already exists", id)
}
```

I suspect that you have called CreateAsset twice *using the same asset ID*. This is not allowed. You cannot create a new asset with the same ID as an asset that already exists. The asset ID is a unique identifier.